# CodeIgniter Accessing Multi-Dimentional Arrays in Views

Tags: php, codeigniter, view, multidimensional-array

I've got a little problemo. In my CodeIgniter Controller I'm loading the same view many times into an array. Each view is assigned to a value, which in turn is added to the $data array to pass to the view. I'm now having problems getting the data back out of the $data array in the master template view.

Here's how I created the array:

```
$data['views'][$current_value][$counter] = $this->load->view('sub_view', $data, true);`
```

This is inside a while loop which cycles through $counter until I've got all the data I need. So the finished array will have views, which have many current values, each which have many counters.

What code should I use to try and get this out of the array in the master view? I've tried so many different methods! It's not playing ball. Has anyone got any ideas. Cheers!

Sparkles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've fixed it. Turns out it was quite a simple mistake, turns out my knowledge of multi-dimensional arrays in CodeIgniter is not bad. Byeee x